# PHP7 session warning - session_write_close

Tags: php, php-7

With an upgrade to from PHP5.6 to PHP7, I am confronted with this error:

```
sapi_apache2.c(326): PHP Warning:  session_write_close(): Failed to write session data (user). Please verify that the current setting of session.save_path is correct (/var/lib/php/7.0/session)
```

This is odd, because we use a custom session handler, which writes to a database.

What changed in PHP7?

Answer (score 7):

The PHP warning is misleading in this situation, because the session is not writing to that directory.

PHP7 is stricter than PHP5.6 when evaluating the return value of the custom session handler.  If that write method returns back FALSE, it will trigger this warning when calling session_write_close.  See: [PHP write-session documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/sessionhandlerinterface.write.php)

So the solution here is to always return back TRUE from the write-session method.  If there is an error, it is probably best managed through exceptions, not a return value.

Comment: To be precise: There was a bug in PHP 5 where the return values weren't properly checked, and PHP 7 just fixed the bug. :) See https://wiki.php.net/rfc/session.user.return-value

Comment: @Narf  I don't know if this is possible, but the PHP warning message probably should be adjusted in the case of a custom session handler.  It appears that there is a write error to the default session directory, but that is not the real error here.

Comment: It's only confusing because your implementation ignores it ... The path displayed in the error message comes from `session.save_path`, which a userspace handler is also *supposed* to use - that's why it exists as a parameter in `SessionHandlerInterface::open()`.

Comment: To clarify, whatever is set in `session.save_path` will be passed to `open()` in your handler. :)

Comment: @Narf  I see your point.  Of course, PHP has no idea what is going on with the custom session handler.